# Sad and worried did l committed shirk

Tags: shirk

I have a big  problem l was thinking with my heart or saying to myself about  bad things. I did not say them out loud but then l had a big doubt about my belief. When l wanted to ask allah for forgiveness l had thoughts or worry l wasn't a beliver. And emotions came to me that l didn't know if am a be liver. Am muslim

Any muslim who can answer this help me out please answer ,email quickly.

Comment: This is not shirk because you didn't associate Allah with anoyone nor you worhsipped anyone except Him so don't be sad and forget about it

Answer (score 0):

Salam, please never act upon these thoughts. They are from shayatiin and/or jinn and wiswas. “There is no sin for you in that which ye proclaim or hide in your minds.”

(Q, 2:235)
Just because you get these thoughts, it doesn’t hold you against the sin. Try to brush them or ignore them. I deal with these too and it’s hard. It’ll be easy if you keep your deen in mind and miracles of the Quran.

Comment: But l think l get these thoughts purposely and

Answer (score 0):

I get these sometimes too. I have two hadith to share with you that really helped me.

*It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) observed:
Verily Allah forgave my people the evil promptings which arise within their hearts as long as they did not speak about them or did not act upon them.*

https://sunnah.com/muslim:127a

*It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that some people from amongst the Companions of the Apostle (ﷺ) came to him and said:
Verily we perceive in our minds that which every one of us considers it too grave to express. He (the Holy Prophet) said: Do you really perceive it? They said: Yes. Upon this he remarked: That is the faith manifest.*

https://sunnah.com/muslim:132a

Realizing these are bad thoughts and therefore not acting upon them or speaking them is a sign of a person's faith. Verily Allah has already forgiven the ummah of Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) for these thoughts.